# Manually adding a Vue component and binding the data to a local data variable

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Usually I am using my TextField component as following:

```
<TextField v-model="name"
  name="name"
  :rules="{required:true}"
  :label="$t('My super textfield')" />
```

at one point in my application, where there is a more complex structure, I have to manually append/render this VueComponent to a div, what works fine with that:

```
import TextField from './Form/TextField';
const TextFieldClass = Vue.extend(TextField);

// ...


  data() {
    return {
      fieldValues: {
      'foo': 'bar'
      }
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    const self = this;

    this.$refs.xyz.someCallback((type, label, id, parent) => {
      const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      parent.appendChild(wrapper);
  
      new TextFieldClass({
        propsData: {
          name: 'input-' + id, 
          id, // id = 'foo'
          label,
          placeholder: label,
          type: 'text',
          value: self.fieldValues[id]
        },
      }).$mount(wrapper);
    });
  },
```

This is working fine, I see the TextField is correctly appended with value 'bar' and I can interact with it. But when I do changes at this field, the changes are not reflected in `this.fieldValues['foo']`

Means,

`<p>{{ fieldValues['foo'] }}</p>` is always printing `bar`, even if I edit the TextField.

My question: How can I bind the local variable fieldValues['foo'] to the value of the TextField, so that it always reflects the current state of input? Thanks in advance.